# Method overriding in an inherited record

Tags: c#, record, c#-10.0

Is it expected behavior with records in C#10?

```cs
Console.WriteLine(new Derived1()); // =output=> Derived1 { }
Console.WriteLine(new Derived2()); // =output=> Base

record Base
{
    public override string ToString() => "Base";
}

record Derived1 : Base;

record Derived2 : Base
{
    public override string ToString() => base.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Compiler [will automatically generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#built-in-formatting-for-display) formatting for display by overriding `ToString` for every record:

> Record types have a compiler-generated `ToString` method that displays the names and values of public properties and fields. The `ToString` method returns a string of the following format:
>
> `<record type name> { <property name> = <value>, <property name> = <value>, ...}`

unless you override it yourself (as you do in `Derived2` and `Base`).

See the [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUATgUwMYHs4BMAEAhAhgZwVgG9ZNzMQBmTFANwTjgEt0FKIAGTAFRQGUALiwB2AcwAUASkwBeAHyYARHkJKA3LAC+sWIlQZMAEUbMG6CJgBcOAgk0wgA==) decompilation.

Also note next:

> In C# 10 and later, your implementation of `ToString` may include the `sealed` modifier, which prevents the compiler from synthesizing a ToString implementation for any derived records.

So if your base implementation is sufficient you can just seal it to prevent compiler from generating overrides:

```cs
record Base
{
    public sealed override string ToString() => "Base";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Especially for the `sealed`. So I'm trying to get that this is expected but do you or anybody else know the reason why is it decided to go this way? To me it sounds a little confusing and inconvenient.

Comment: @AlexKovanev you can dive into [LDM notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39). But I would say it is done for consistency with other methods.